# (coc.nvim) error: Warning: The 'x' rule requires type information

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc

I'm using `coc.nvim` for `react (typescript)` development. I have installed following `coc` plugins.

- coc-tslint-plugin
- coc-tsserver
- coc-prettier

`tslint` integration is enabled for prettier in `coc-settings.json`.

```
"prettier.eslintIntegration": true,
"prettier.tslintIntegration": true,
"prettier.stylelintIntegration": true,
coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes": ["typescriptreact"],
```

When a `tsx` is saved, it formats the file but it is logging following warning messages.

```
[coc.nvim] error: Warning: The 'no-array-mutation' rule requires type information.
[coc.nvim] error: Warning: The 'no-object-mutation' rule requires type information.
[coc.nvim] error: Warning: The 'promise-function-async' rule requires type information.
[coc.nvim] error: Warning: The 'await-promise' rule requires type information.
[coc.nvim] error: Warning: The 'no-floating-promises' rule requires type information.
[coc.nvim] error: Warning: The 'no-for-in-array' rule requires type information.
[coc.nvim] error: Warning: The 'no-inferred-empty-object-type' rule requires type information.
[coc.nvim] error: Warning: The 'no-null-undefined-union' rule requires type information.
[coc.nvim] error: Warning: The 'no-restricted-globals' rule requires type information.
[coc.nvim] error: Warning: The 'no-unbound-method' rule requires type information.
[coc.nvim] error: Warning: The 'no-unsafe-any' rule requires type information.
[coc.nvim] error: Warning: The 'no-void-expression' rule requires type information.
[coc.nvim] error: Warning: The 'restrict-plus-operands' rule requires type information.
```

How do I enable type information for `coc.prettier`?

Answer (score 0):

After a quick [google](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%5Bcoc.nvim%5D+error:+Warning:+The+%27no-array-mutation%27+rule+requires+type+information.&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), I found [this](https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader/issues/107), which suggests this is not a coc.nvim issue, but a typescript configuration issue.

> my understanding is you'd need to provide the `typeCheck: true` config option to ts-loader, at the cost of tslint running slower

That said, the issue hasn't had much activity in a year.